# Non-optional values in Swift-structure returns optional values

Tags: swift, struct, option-type

I have a structure in one ViewController which has a couple of non-optional members like:

```
struct MyStruct {
    let id: Int64!
    let name: String!
    func checkValues() -> Bool {
        if id == nil || name == nil {
            return false
        } else {
            print("id: \(id) name: \(name)"); return true
        }
    }
}
```

I create an instance of the struct in another VC (`let temp = ViewController.MyStruct(id: 10, name: "Example")`) and pass it to the one where I created the struct via a Segue. When executing `temp.checkValues()` I get

```
id: Optional(10) name: Optional("Example")
```

From my understanding of (non-)optionals I shouldn't get the `Optional()` since I declared the variables with `!`. Did I get it wrong? Right now I just put an exclamation mark whenever I use it. I also tried using `init`  in the struct but that didn't change anything.
Since this is not as intended (if I'm right) I fear I didn't get the full concept... Please tell me what is wrong with my code / me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Did I get it wrong?

Yes. Your variables **are** optionals - the `!` operator is a *force unwrap* operator, so your variables are *implicitly unwrapped*. If you don't want your variables to be optionals, just drop `!`.

The `!` operator exists in Swift to facilitate bridging from Objective-C, for instance for `IBOutlet` variables. Using `!` operator aside from that is a bad practice.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That makes sense... I had the wrong impression that when adding the `!` I would make sure that they cannot be optionals...

Answer (score 5):

`!` is an **implictly unwrapped optional**. Everything variable declaration's type that ends with `!` **is** an optional. You dont have to declare them to be `Optional`s. Just use them normally and the initializer will take care of them:

```
struct MyStruct {
    let id: Int64
    let name: String
    func checkValues() -> Bool {
        print("id: \(id) name: \(name)"); return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! That makes sense...